# Connect to Orbot Socks5 proxy from computer on same network

Tags: orbot, proxy

I want to use Orbot on my phone as a proxy server for my desktop or any computer on my local network. How/can I set Orbot up to let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Orbot->settings. Scroll down until you find "debug".There is option called "Torrc Custom config". Click on it,enter ip and port using this command: `SOCKSPort <localIP>:9050`

Comment: Please explain the steps so that we can use it as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling the tethering mode, if your device is rooted. It should enable the SOCKS proxy to be bound to the 0.0.0.0 interface, which means other devices can see it on the network. If you know the IP address of your device, you can find the SOCKS proxy at port 9050.

Comment: How can I do this without tethering?